# Conditional insert failing in HSQL

Tags: mybatis, hsqldb

I am using HSQL for executing a conditional insert and it keeps failing with exception.

Java + MyBatis + HSQL

Query :

```
INSERT INTO CATS (ID, NAME) 
SELECT #{id}, #{name}
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * from CATS WHERE NAME = #{name})
```

Exception :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: WHERE in statement [INSERT INTO CATS (ID, NAME) select ?, ? WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from CATS WHERE NAME = ?)]
[junit]     at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
[junit]     at org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledConnection.invoke(PooledConnection.java:245)
[junit]     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
```

I checked if conditional inserts are not supported in HSQL. But that doesn't seem to be the case

I have already executed `set database sql syntax pgs true`, so there should not be any issue with executing RAW postgres queries in HSQL

Answer (score 1):

When you want to get column dynamically,you need to use `$` instead of `#`

```
INSERT INTO CATS (ID, NAME) 
SELECT ${id}, ${name}
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * from CATS WHERE NAME = #{name})
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that my conditional insert query is postgres specific and cannot be executed in HSQL. I went with using [otj-pg-embedded](https://github.com/opentable/otj-pg-embedded) for run time postgres instance instead of HSQL and the query worked.